# Open NSWindowController from NSMenu

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I'm with a NSMenu in an agent application *(without the icon in the dock)*. When a button from this menu is tapped, I want to show a generic NSWindowController.

My menu button action:

```
- (IBAction)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender {    
    MyWindowController *myWindow = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowController"];

    [myWindow showWindow:nil];
    [[myWindow window] makeMainWindow];
}
```

But the window just "flashes" in the screen (it shows and disappears really fast).

Any solution?

Comment: Does your project use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?

Comment: @NSGod Yes, my project uses ARC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason the window is showing up for a split second and then disappearing has to do with ARC and how you go about creating the instance of the window controller:

```
- (IBAction)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender {    
    MyWindowController *myWindow = [[MyWindowController alloc]
                    initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowController"];
    [myWindow showWindow:nil];
    [[myWindow window] makeMainWindow];
}
```

Under ARC, the `myWindow` instance will be valid for the scope where it is defined. In other words, after the last `[[myWindow window] makeMainWindow];` line is reached and run, the window controller will be released and deallocated, and as a result, its window will be removed from the screen.

Generally speaking, for items or objects you create that you want to "stick around", you should define them as an instance variable with a `strong` property.

For example, your .h would look something like this:

```
@class MyWindowController;

@interface MDAppController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyWindowController *windowController;

@end
```

And the revised `menuButtonTapped:` method would look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (self.windowController == nil) {
         self.windowController = [[MyWindowController alloc]
            initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowController"];
    }
    [self.windowController showWindow:nil];
}
```

Comment: Wow! I don't know how I didn't realize it before. Thanks, NSGod! :)

Comment: like your answer and that very helpful for newbie of mac osx development.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[[myWindow window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Comment: No. I think that the window isn't showing because my app is agent (doesn't have the dock icon) and I don't have a main window (as cocoa's main templates).

Comment: As far as I know, that doesn't make a difference. Try playing with the "visible at launch" options for the window. If that doesn't work, is there anything in MyWindowController that could interfere?

Comment: Changing the "Main nib file base name" opens the window controller normally. Deselecting/selecting the "visible at launch" doesn't affect anything.