# Show NSWindowController from StatusMenu

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have an app working from an extension in the Status Menu.

I have there a button "Settings" on which when the user taps should launch a particular view of my storyboard.

I have tried many different ways, [Open NSWindowController from NSMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441718/open-nswindowcontroller-from-nsmenu), [Cocoa - How to bring particular window to come in foreground from StatusMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287691/cocoa-how-to-bring-particular-window-to-come-in-foreground-from-statusmenu).

Here is my current code :

```
StatusMenu.swift

func showSettings() {

  var mainWindowController = MainWindowController()
  mainWindowController.showWindow(nil)

}

MainWindowController.swift

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

 override func windowDidLoad() {
   super.windowDidLoad()

   self.window?.center()
   self.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
   NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)

   }

}
```

Comment: move mainWindowController declaration out of your showSettings  method

Comment: @LeoDabus only the first line ? It doesn't work...

Comment: Are you sure window property it is not nil?

Comment: @LeoDabus yes... is it because I'm calling a specific NSWindowController in my storyboard ? I saw some other solutions requiring the windowNibName function

Answer (score 0):

The code posted has 2 potential issues:

1. `MainWindowController.init` is not implemented by `NSWindowController` but `NSObject`, that means unlike for NSViewControllers, this does *not* lookup the Nib file of the same name. Use this:

   ```
   extension MainWindowController {
       convenience init() {
           self.init(windowNibName: .init(rawValue: "MainWindowController"))
       }
   }
   ```
2. The resulting instance is referenced from `mainWindowController`, but this variable only has local scope to `showSettings()`. That means, once `showSettings()` is done, the garbage collector will release the object again. It's as good as never having stored it. You need to keep a permanent reference in an object that lives on, or as a global variable, as in:

   ```
    // Assuming your StatusMenu instance is strongly referenced for the whole runtime
    class StatusMenu {
        var mainWindowController: MainWindowController?
        func showSettings() {
           self.mainWindowController = MainWindowController()
           self.mainWindowController?.showWindow(nil)
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution but I'm not able to use ".init"... Is it Swift 4?

Comment: Yes, it's short for `NSNib.Name(rawValue:)` in this context; in Swift 3, you should be able to pass the String directly.

Comment: OK thanks, I just tried and I have the error : "Failed to lad window nib file "MainWindowController", is the problem that my nib is in my storyboard ?